# Generalisation of chinese remainder theorem on ideals of ring without 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $I_1,\dots,I_n$ be (two-sided) ideals of a ring $R$ (not necessarily with 1), which are pairwise co-maximal, i.e. $\forall i\ne j\in \mathbb{Z}_{[1,n]}$, $I_i+I_j=R$.

Let $f:R\to R/I_1\times R/I_2\times\dots\times R/I_n$, defined by $r\mapsto(r+I_1,r+I_2,\dots,r+I_n)$.

Is $f$ surjective even when $R$ does not have a 1?

Note: In my course, a ring $R$ satisfies:

1. $R$ is an Abelian (commutative) group under $+$.
2. Multiplication is associative.
3. $+$ and $\times$ satisfy distributive laws: $r(s+t)=rs+rt$ and $(r+s)t=rt+st$.

Of course, I would be still interested if you have a proof when $R$ is commutative for $\times$.

Comment: Mmm, a ring without 1... can you think of a specific ring like that with those pairwise co-maximal ideals?

Comment: It was an unanswered question from my algebra course. It was true if for the special case when there are two ideals, and I got the same proof as the one at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202113/proof-of-chinese-remainder-theorem-for-ring

Comment: Is the ring commutative, though? When dropping axioms, you should be very precise as to what axioms you're dropping.

Comment: I should be honest with you, I can't be of much help on this question. Mostly I'm interested in commutative rings with units. I had to Google "rings without 1" to even begin to wrap my mind around this concept. The first example I found was $R = 2\mathbb{Z}$, but I couldn't tell you if that has ideals satisfying the pairwise co-maximality requirement.

Comment: @RobertSoupe: a more natural example (I think) is the ring of continuous functions vanishing at infinity in some noncompact space (e.g. $C_0({\bf R})$ or $c_0$, the space of sequences convergent to zero).

Comment: @tomasz Alright, I added the definition of "ring". Does it being commutative make it much different?

Comment: @user1537366L: I don't know, really, but it might. If it is non-commutative, you should specify that those ideals are left ideals. Or are they two-sided?

Comment: @tomasz Yes, two-sided.

Comment: @RobertSoupe: or now that we're also noncommutative, compact operators on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. ;)